# Rotate UIView without deformation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, rotation, accelerometer

I'm rotating a UIView based on the accelerometer data, and it works fine except that the UIView is deformed. I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Here's the code in my didAccelerate method:

```
float kFilteringFactor = 0.175;
CGFloat x = acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor + acceleration.x * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
CGFloat y = acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor + acceleration.y * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
float radians = M_PI - atan2(y, x);
[_horizonView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians)];
```

Am I performing the rotation incorrectly? I've changed the origin point in Xcode, but that appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

what kind of deformation occures? I think the the rotation is fine.

Comment: If I have the UIView as a rectangle in the middle, it shrinks, until at 45 degrees it disappears completely then grows > 45 degrees. I thought I might be needing to translate to the origin first, then rotate and translate back, but when I do that the rotation doesn't occur at all.

Comment: The rotation is applied around the anchorPoint of the UIView's layer, which is the layer's center (0.5, 0.5). So no extra translation needed. I simulated your code with a simple red rectangle, and it does what you want. What extra modification do you do on the `_horizonView `?

Comment: None. I just recreated the project from scratch to eliminate any weird change, but its still the same. I can't figure it. Could it be something to do with the coordinate system of the ViewController? All I've done is add a view, set its background, make an outlet to it in my ViewController, then implement the didAccelerate method with the code above, and initialise the accelerometer in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ah man, I just fixed it by unchecking Use Autolayout in the File Inspector. Thanks very much for your help Peteee